# how to fix 500 internal server error in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

help please iv changed the URL of my WordPress website in general setting and after that i get this error: 500 internal server error
I'm trying to add this following code `update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );` to my function.php file but without any result. and i don't have access to my database.

Comment: do you have shell access to the server

Comment: define it in wp-config

Comment: @Stender i'v tryed this also but still the same problem

Comment: Do you still have the problem, if you remove the s again?

Comment: @Stender yes the same problem

Comment: Please Debug ON then let us know the error.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a New .htaccess File

Increasing Your PHP Memory Limit in WordPress using WP Config
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Comment: that's does not solve my problem because the url is changing